# Decrypt a portion of a corrupted drive

Tags: partition, encryption, ext4, luks

I have a hard drive that got corrupted after a doing an MTP mounting of a cell phone.  It was created under Fedora Core 20 using defaults.  Originally, I thought I did it as an ext4 partition.  I tried mounting it as an ext4 it couldn't and fsck reported corrupt superblocks.  The TestDisk program couldn't determine what the partition was either.  Out of desperation, I created new superblocks as follows:

```
mke2fs -n -b 2048 /dev/sdb3
```

The partition could still not be mounted.  Later saw from a grub.cfg file the following line

```
linuxefi /vmlinuz-3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_dfl-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora_dfl/swap vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd.lvm.lv=fedora_dfl/root rd.luks.uuid=luks-a0d2613e-ce2a-4a6b-96cf-b999b3a36ab8  rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

My guess is that I created an encrypted volume and forgot that I did so.  Fortunately, I only use a few passwords so guessing which one I used shouldn't be too hard.

In a perfect world, I'd love to have the full volume back.  However, I hope to get back a couple of files.

Comment: If you did corrupt encrypted data, the amount of data lost will be dependent on the block cipher mode of operation that was chosen. With some the corruption is localized to the block, with others, every block after and including the corrupted block is lost.

Comment: This is the problem of using encryption. After in the past losing data to compressed and encrypted volumes, either to bugs in implementation, hardware and power failures, I nowadays do not worry about it. I do worry about securing it from remote access though.

Comment: @cremefraiche that's a sobering thought. Do you know if luks/dm-crypt uses any "every block after is lost" formats? Or any common encryption that does, like truecrypt, eCryptFS, gpg, EncFS, bitlocker, mac's filevault?

Comment: @Xen2050 I have only researched ECB, CBC, CFB, and OFB block cipher modes. Of those, ECB and CFB will only lose data in the corrupted block, however I would recommend avoiding ECB. The way it encrypts blocks is far less secure than other methods. [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) has a lot more info. You should be able to find out the default block cipher modes for all of those with a little searching.

Comment: @cremefraiche Apparently my cryptsetup uses defaults plain: aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 & LUKS1: aes-xts-plain64. Wikipedia says CBC has "Random Read Access: Yes" so that *sounds* like only corrupted areas are lost... or does it? I think I'll do a little searching or even testing to see if a few random bytes will bork all the rest

Comment: @Xen2050 CBC and OFB WILL lose all data after corrupted block, ECB and CFB will NOT. This can be understood from looking at the diagrams in the link I gave, or using the method I used to test these myself. Create a text file several times larger than the block size you are using (c/p'ing a paragraph is fine), encrypt the text file with all of the block modes you would like to test, then open the encrypted files in `bless` hex editor. Edit a single byte in each file(corruption), decrypt the files, then open in a text editor. Then see for yourself which modes lose data after corruption.

Comment: @cremefraiche Luckily `cryptsetup` does **NOT** suffer from the single byte "derails the rest of the train" problem. Both LUKS's aes-xts-plain64 and plain dm-crypt's aes-**cbc**-essiv:sha256 only suffered 16 or 17 byte corruption when one byte was changed in the unencrypted base file. Even changing 100 consecutive bytes in the plain dm-crypt encrypted file only changed 126 bytes in the decrypted device & the file on it. All bytes before & after are A-OK.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends whether you've actually overwritten the beginning of the partition or not. If you have, your data is unrecoverable unless you've made a backup of the key. (Not the password: the key.) If you haven't, just open the encrypted volume and supply the password normally.

The password is only used to generate a key encryption key. This key encryption key is in turn only used to decrypt the data encryption key. The data encryption key is what you need to get any useful data.
The main reason for this two-tier structure is that you can have multiple passwords without having multiple copies of the encrypted data, and you can change the password without re-encrypting all the data.

The data encryption key is stored (in an encrypted form) in one or more keyslots (as many as there are passwords) at the very beginning of the partition, in the first few kilobytes (typically in the first kilobyte, if you've defined a single password).

If you only ran `mke2fs -n -b 2048 /dev/sdb3`, that doesn't actually modify anything thanks to the `-n` option. But if you ran `mke2fs` without `-n`, the key is lost. If you ran `e2fsck` and it changed something, chances are that the key is lost.

Run `file -s /dev/sdb3`. If that tells you that you have a LUKS volume, then the header is probably intact, so all you need to do is remember the password. If that tells you something else, then the header has probably been overwritten and you'd need a backup of the key to recover anything.